# Assigning object to dom element and retrieving it in function

Tags: javascript, object, domdocument

I'm trying to build a parallax plugin by myself using vanilla js. Basically I have set it all up so it works, but what i would like to do is add some helper functions to use later on for each parallax section.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to write something like:

```
document.getElementById('test').parallax.getImage();
```

Inside my js plugin I have defined:

```
var parallax = {

getImage : function(element, event){
    var img = null;
    var section = element;

    for (var i = 0; i < section.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (section.childNodes[i].className == "parallax-image") {
          img = section.childNodes[i];
          break;
        }        
    }
    return img;
},

}
```

and later on in initiation i assign the object to the dom element:

```
function setupParallax(){
    // this get all sections
    var sections = self.methods.getSections();

    for (var i = sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sections[i].parallax = parallax;
    }
}
```

So in the `getImage()` function of the parallax object, I want to retrieve the element the parallax object is assigned to. How do I go about that?

Comment: I honestly don't think I'm following your question (though that's probably a lack of sleep/coffee so far today), but a couple of suggestions: **1:** rather than `section.childNodes` I'd suggest using `section.children`, that way you only retrieve HTMLElement children, and **2:**  rather than `section.childNodes[i].className == "parallax-image"` I'd suggest using `Element.classList`: `section.children[i].classList.contains('parallax-image')`, which returns a Boolean (`true`/`false`) value.

Comment: References: [`parentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: thanks for the input. My experience with vanilla JS is very limited so there is surely lots to optimize.

My problem is, that i can't figure out how to access the dom element i assigned the `parallax` object to - being the section. both the `element` and `event` arguments return undefined. `this` only refers to the `parallax` object. So I'm unsure how to use the dom element inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the *native* `Element` by a `parallax` *namespace* object which has methods like `.getImage()`

```
document.getElementById('test').parallax.getImage()
```

you can use [***Fn*.prototype.call()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to forward the current ***section*** Element to a set of (`_parallax`) methods which will be accessible by using `Element.parallax`

```js
const Parallax = (selector) => {

  const
    _el = document.querySelector(selector),
    _sections = _el.querySelectorAll('.parallax-section'),
    _parallax = section => ({
      getImage() {
        return section.querySelector('.parallax-image');
      },
      // more section parallax methods here
    }),
    methods = {};


  methods.getSections = () => _sections;
  methods.someOtherMethod = (arg) => {
    return arg;
  }

  // Init
  [..._sections].forEach(section => section.parallax = _parallax.call(null, section));

  // Expose methods
  return methods;

};


// Init Parallax on some parent
const myPar = Parallax('#container');

// Testing stuff:
console.log( document.getElementById('test').parallax.getImage() );
console.log( myPar.getSections() )
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="parallax-section">
    <img class="parallax-image" src="//placehold.it/20x20/0bf">
  </div>

  <div id="test" class="parallax-section">
    <img class="parallax-image" src="//placehold.it/20x20/f0b">
  </div>

</div>
```

The above's `getImage()` is the exact simpler way of your `getImage()` method. If `section.querySelector('.parallax-image')` finds no image, it will return `null` - just like your code does.

Comment: This looks like just what I needed. Better late than never!